# Как запустить асинхронный код в pytest?

Tags: python, асинхронность, pytest

Есть класс, который подключается в `rabbitmq` и читает очередь. В самом классе есть ассинхронные  методы, и стоит задача в `pytest` держать запущенным этот класс, пока другие тесты отработают.

```
class RPCServer:

    def __init__(self,
                 uri: str):
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None
        self.rpc = None
        self.uri = uri
        self.queue = None

    async def start(self):
        timeout = 3
        for i in range(100):
            try:
                logger.info(self.uri)
                self.connection = await ap.connect_robust(
                    url=self.uri,
                    client_properties={"connection_name": "callee"},
                )
                logger.info(f'Got connection')
                break
            except ConnectionError:
                time.sleep(timeout)
                logger.info(f'Sleep timeout {timeout}')
        if not self.connection:
            error = f'Cannot connect to AMQP URI.'
            logger.error(error)
            raise RuntimeError(error)

        logger.info(self.uri)

        self.channel = await self.connection.channel()

        self.rpc = await ap.patterns.RPC.create(self.channel)

        await self.rpc.register(
            'request',
            request,
            durable=True
        )
        return self.connection

    async def stop(self):
        await self.channel.close()
        await self.connection.close()
```

Как сделать чтобы можно было использовать этот класс вот таким образом

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
async def rpc_server():
    server = RPCServer('amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@localhost:5673/')
    await server.start()
    yield server
```

Ну или на крайний случай - запустить скрипт, ждать окончания всех тестов - закрыть процесс.

Comment: Есть плагин [pytest-asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/), попробуйте с ним. Насколько я вижу, асинхронные фикстуры он поддерживает (нужно использовать декоратор `@pytest_asyncio.fixture`).

Comment: ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'event_loop' with a 'session' scoped request object, involved factories

Comment: @insolor вот такая ошибка

Comment: Значит нужно переопределить фикстуру [`event_loop`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/blob/master/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py#L486) с указанием скоупа session